# How to show that $A :=\{(x,y) \in S^2 \times S^2 \mid \langle x,y\rangle =0\}$ is homeomorphic to $SO(3)$

Tags: general-topology

How to show that $A :=\{(x,y) \in S^2 \times S^2 \mid \langle x,y\rangle=0\}$ is homeomorphic to $\operatorname{SO}(3)$? Does proving this require that I know the specific form of the matrices in $\operatorname{SO}(3)$?

Comment: I may be missing something, but what does it mean to take the dot product of an element of $\mathbb{S}^1\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ and an element of $\mathbb{S}^2\subseteq\mathbb{R}^3$? What does $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ stand for?

Comment: What does $\langle x,y \rangle=0$ mean? Should we think of $S^1$ and $S^2$ as being embedded in $\Bbb R^3$?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff That makes sense!

Comment: Or maybe you really mean $\{(x,y)\in S^2\times S^2: \langle x,y\rangle = 0\}$. This will have dimension $3$ (as does $SO(3)$), whereas, however we interpret your set, it has dimension $2$.

Comment: I am so sorry, it should be $S^2 \times S^2$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Take $e_1,e_2,e_3$ to be standard basis of ${\bf R}^3$. If $A\in \operatorname{SO}(3)$, then $A(e_1)$ can be any unit vector, $A(e_2)$ can be any unit vector orthogonal to $A(e_1)$, and $A(e_3)$ is uniquely determined by $A(e_1)$ and $A(e_2)$.

All you really need is the definition of the special orthogonal group and elementary facts about inner product spaces. There is no need to use matrices at all.

Comment: How is this related to $S^2 \times S^2$

Comment: @Adam: $S^2$ is the space of unit vectors in ${\bf R}^3$.

Comment: I see. One more question, suppose that I have two orthogonal vectors $a,b$ such that $|a|=|b| = 1$ and $a,b$ are orthogonal. How would I show that there is a unique unit vector $c$ such that is orthogoal to both $a$ and $b$ and the determinant of the matrix formed by $a,b,c$ as row vectors is 1. Is it possible to write $c$ in terms of $a$ and $b$?

Comment: @Adam: There are two unit vectors $c$ (in a three dimensional space) orthogonal to $a$ and $b$ simultaneously, and they are opposite to one another. The difference between them is the orientation of the  triple $(a,b,c)$ (flipping the sign of one vector flips the orientation). But is you use the *special* orthogonal group, the orientation is fixed. So in terms of $a$ and $b$, $c$ is the vector orthogonal to $a$ and $b$ such that $(a,b,c)$ has the same orientation as $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$.

Comment: Yes, but in order to prove that it is a homeomorphism, I need to write down $c$ explicitly. Is there an explicit formula for $c$?

Comment: @Adam: You could write it in terms of determinants/cross products, but you really don't need it. There is no need to use any coordinates whatsoever.